# execvp - ls: fts_open: No such file or directory

Tags: c, exec, fork, execvp

I'm currently struggling with this error. I'm writing a shell emulator, using fork() for executing a command using execvp();.
Almost every command I try to parse to my shell is working perfectly, except for ls without arguments.
If I try to execute ls -lah, everything works, but a simple ls won't, receiving the following error:

```
ls: fts_open: No such file or directory
```

Here is a snippet of my code: (just the essential)

```
pid = fork();
      if (pid==0)
      {
        puts("CHILD");
        puts(args[0]);
        puts(args[1]);
        printf("%d\n", strlen(args[1]));
        args[2] = NULL;
        execvp(args[0], args);
      }
      else wait(NULL);
      puts("BACK TO PARENT");
    }
```

and here is the output for ls:

```
ls
CHILD
ls

0
ls: fts_open: No such file or directory
BACK TO PARENT
```

as you can see, args[0] contains ls, args[1] is empty, as there are no arguments, the length of args[1] is 0, but i keep getting the error.

Any idea on what it could be?

EDIT:

Kudos for Jonathan Leffler for finding it out: (also, it seems like it is just an issue on Mac)

The point is that args[1] is not really empty, so, the OS tries to open the '' file, which, obviously, does not exists, and, by what is looks, can't be created, since it is not really a name.

So, Here is what I did: check the len of args[1]. If it is 0, set it to NULL. (just freeing the memory did not really helped)

```
pid = fork();
      if (pid==0)
      {
        puts("CHILD");
        puts(args[0]);
        puts(args[1]);
        if (strlen(args[1]) == 0)
            args[1] = 0;
        args[2] = NULL;
        execvp(args[0], args);
      }
      else wait(NULL);
      puts("BACK TO PARENT");
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the complete definition of `args` (what `args[1]` is set to, what is "empty"?), as well as more of your code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there are no more arguments, the pointer should be null, not a non-null pointer to a zero length string.

```
pid = fork();
if (pid==0)
{
    puts("CHILD");
    puts(args[0]);
    fflush(stdout);
    args[1] = 0;
    execvp(args[0], args);
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to exec %s\n", args[0]);
    exit(1);
}
else
    wait(NULL);
puts("BACK TO PARENT");
```

Just out of pure curiosity, I tried this at my command line:

```
$ ls ''
ls: fts_open: No such file or directory
$
```

Are you running on a Mac too?  (To say I was surprised to see the same message doesn't begin to describe my reaction!)  What's more intriguing is that creating a file `fts_open` doesn't seem to get rid of the error message.  Weird behaviour by `ls`, but in response to an invalid request (there are no file names that are the empty string).

Comment: Thanks! I will update my question to show how my code became, but, basically, I checked the len of args[1] and, if it is 0, just made it NULL.

Comment: Yes, I'm running on Mac as well. I made a couple of fast research, and it seems like fts_open is something OS-related. Probably regarding to file opening.

Comment: `fts_open` is the internal function to traverse directory hierarchies. The error message means the error occurred in the program `ls`, in the function `fts_open`, which returned the error code `ENOENT`.